# Method - calling methods

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rectangle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    -Don't know how to call method here-
}

/**
 * returns the area of a rectangle
 * @param height the height of the rectangle
 * @param width the width of the rectangle
 */
public static int area (int length, int width)
{
    return length * width;
}

/**
 * returns the perimeter of a rectangle
 * @param height the height of the rectangle
 * @param width the width of the rectangle
 */
public static int perimeter (int length, int width)
{
    return length + width;
}

/**
 * returns the details of the rectangle
 * @param height the height of the rectangle
 * @param width the width of the rectangle
 */
public static void printRectangleDetails (int length, int width)
{
    System.out.println ("This is the length of the rectangle " + length);

    System.out.println ("This is the width of the rectangle " + width);

    System.out.println (("This is the perimeter of the rectangle " + (length + width)));

    System.out.println (("This is the area of the rectangle " + (length * width)));
}

/**
 * Read in an integer and return its value
 * @param the prompt to be shown to the user
 */
public static int readInteger(String prompt)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    return input;
}
```

}

I'm trying to call the method readInteger to prompt the user to insert the rectangle's height and width. This is my first experience with methods so any help would be appreciated, I'm also not sure if the readInteger method is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: What all places or books did you referred, that didn't make you understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main()` method, you can read the length and width of the rectangle by calling the `readInteger()` method that you have created in the `Rectangle` class as:

```
 int length = readInteger(" For Length ");
 int width = readInteger("For Width ");
 printRectangleDetails(length,width);
```

First of all, add this line to readInteger() method:

```
  System.out.println (prompt);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it working now. Makes sense now I actually see the proper code.

Answer (score 2):

You call a method, typical with the following syntax:

```
methodName();
```

Example:

To call the area method you say:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      area(2,3);
 }
```

Note: the object is implied in this case since your area method is public and static to the rectangle class which contains the main method.

If area was in a different class you would make the call the method differently, by instantiation first and then a method call on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.print("Enter length : " );
    int len=Integer.parseInt( s.nextLine()) ;
    System.out.print("\nEnter width : ");
    int wd=Integer.parseInt( s.nextLine()) ;
    printRectangleDetails(len,wd);     
 }
```